# c# ошибка при сериализации

Tags: c#, serialize

Собственно текст ошибки:

> InnerException System.ArgumentException: ".", шестнадцатеричное
>   значение 0x00, является недопустимым знаком.    в
>   System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.InvalidXmlChar(Int32 ch, Char*
>   pDst, Boolean entitize)    в
>   System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(Char* pSrc,
>   Char* pSrcEnd)    в
>   System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)    в
>   System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)    в
>   System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteElementString(String localName, String ns,
>   String value)    в
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteElementString(String
>   localName, String ns, String value, XmlQualifiedName xsiType)    в
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteElementString(String
>   localName, String ns, String value)

Код:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T value)
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms,
            new XmlWriterSettings()
            {
                Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true),
                Indent = false,
                NewLineOnAttributes = false,
            }))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xw, value);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
 }
```

Проблема в том, что данная ошибка выпадает не на всех клиентских машинах. У кого-то все проходит отлично. 
Уважаемые эксперты, помогите, пожалуйста. Поскажите с чем это может быть связано.
Я с с# очень-очень "на вы", учусь, скажем так, по необходимости.
Если информации выше мало - добавлю, только скажите, что интересует.
И еще, на клиенте, на котором выпадает эта ошибка, сериализация в файл проходит без проблем.

Comment: Не помешало бы знать, какой именно класс сериализируется.

Comment: Передается свой класс Request c DataTable внутри.